# Magento 2 CE standalone database

Tags: magento2

In according with [realease notes](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/magento/release-notes-ce-2.0.html) about magento 2 community edition I think that I can setup a standalone database for key subsystem.

> Standalone databases for key subsystems like order management, product
>   management and checkout; combined with support for MySQL Cluster,
>   enable Magento to scale to handle rapid growth.

But i can't find anything about this. So where I can find something about? 
Is this feature for community edition (i suppose because is under release notes about magento 2 CE) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is mistake. This functionality available only in EE edition